# OpenCV : How to replace a bigger rect with a smaller rect

Tags: opencv

I am doing some operation where I need to replace the bigger rectangle with the smaller rectangle.

Most answers suggested to use `smallerRectMat.copyTo(biggerRectMat)` but it didn't give me the require output. The submat is changed but the original image is as it is.

And when I try to see the submat both became same of same smaller rectangle size.

```
Mat rectNose = testBuffer.submat(rectA.y,rectA.y+rectA.height,rectA.x,rectC.x+rectC.width);
Rect biggerRect = getHeadContour(testBuffer);
Mat rectHead = testBuffer.submat(biggerRect.y+1,biggerRect.y+biggerRect.height,biggerRect.x+1,biggerRect.x+biggerRect.width);
rectNose.copyTo(rectHead);
Imgcodecs.imwrite("/Users/test.jpg",rectHead);
Imgcodecs.imwrite("/Users/test1.jpg",rectNose);
Imgcodecs.imwrite("/Users/test1.jpg",testBuffer);
```

Basically I want to copy the rectangle near the nose region to the rectangle with blue boundary at forehead.

[image]

Comment: Your code overwrites test1.jpg!

Comment: @zeFrenchy typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try ROI(Region Of Image) scaling

```
smallRect = img[rectA.y:rectA.y+rectA.height, rectA.x:rectC.x+rectC.width]
upscaledRegion = cv2.resize(smallRect , (biggerRect.width, biggerRect.height), interpolation=cv2.INTER_AREA)
img[biggerRect.y:biggerRect.y+biggerRect.height, biggerRect.x:biggerRect.x+biggerRect.width] = upscaledRegion
```